# OAuth 2.0 Login (early version) deprecated & ASP.NET Owin

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, google-api, owin

According to Google they are deprecating the OAuth 2.0 Login (early version):

https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#oid2

Does Asp.Net Owin work with this early version?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET OWIN can handle both. See the following link on how to switch to the new version: [Changes to Google OAuth 2.0 and updates in Google middleware for 3.0.0 RC release](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/07/02/changes-to-google-oauth-2-0-and-updates-in-google-middleware-for-3-0-0-rc-release.aspx)